# Web-scraping through a rotating proxy script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, proxy

I've created a script in python which is able to parse proxies (supposed to support "https") from a website. Then the script will use those proxies randomly to parse the title of different coffe shops from a website. With every new request, the script is supposed to use new proxies. I've tried my best to make it flawless. The scraper is doing fine at this moment.

I'll be happy to shake off any redundancy within my script (I meant DRY) or to bring about any change to make it better.

This is the complete approach:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from random import choice

links = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}'.format(page) for page in range(1,6)]

def get_proxies():
    link = 'https://www.sslproxies.org/'   
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    proxies = [':'.join([item.select_one("td").text,item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text]) for item in soup.select("table.table tr") if "yes" in item.text]
    return proxies  #producing list of proxies that supports "https"

def check_proxy(session, proxy_list=get_proxies(), validated=False):
    proxy = choice(proxy_list)
    session.proxies = {'https': 'https://{}'.format(proxy)}
    try:
        print(session.get('https://httpbin.org/ip').json())
        validated = True  #try to make sure it is a working proxy
        return
    except Exception: pass

    while True:
        proxy = choice(proxy_list)
        session.proxies = {'https': 'https://{}'.format(proxy)}
        if not validated:  #otherwise get back to ensure it does fetch a working proxy
            print("-------go validate--------")
            return

def parse_content(url):
    ua = UserAgent()
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
    check_proxy(session)  #collect a working proxy to be used to fetch a valid response

    while True:
        try:
            response = session.get(url)
            break     #as soon as it fetch a valid response, it will break out of the while loop to continue with the rest
        except Exception as e:
            session.headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
            check_proxy(session)  #if exception is raised, start over again
            parse_content(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    for items in soup.select(".info span[itemprop='name']"):
        print(items.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in links:
        parse_content(link)
```

Comment: except /pass is usually a bad idea. You'll want to at least know which exceptions to swallow and which ones to print.

Comment: Why are you reassigning session.proxies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description you want your code to perform these tasks:

1. Get a list of proxies
2. That support https
3. That are actually working

And you want that list to be randomized (from your description without repetition, from your code repetitions are fine).

I would use a couple of generators for that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from random import shuffle


def get_proxies(link):  
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    https_proxies = filter(lambda item: "yes" in item.text,
                           soup.select("table.table tr"))
    for item in https_proxies:
        yield "{}:{}".format(item.select_one("td").text,
                             item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text)

def get_random_proxies_iter():
    proxies = list(get_proxies('https://www.sslproxies.org/'))
    shuffle(proxies)
    return iter(proxies)  # iter so we can call next on it to get the next proxy


def get_proxy(session, proxies, validated=False):
    session.proxies = {'https': 'https://{}'.format(next(proxies))}
    if validated:
        while True:
            try:
                return session.get('https://httpbin.org/ip').json()
            except Exception:
                session.proxies = {'https': 'https://{}'.format(next(proxies))}


def get_response(url):
    session = requests.Session()
    ua = UserAgent()
    proxies = get_random_proxies_iter()
    while True:
        try:
            session.headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
            print(get_proxy(session, proxies, validated=True))  #collect a working proxy to be used to fetch a valid response
            return session.get(url) # as soon as it fetches a valid response, it will break out of the while loop
        except StopIteration:
            raise  # No more proxies left to try
        except Exception:
            pass  # Other errors: try again


def parse_content(url):
    response = get_response(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    for items in soup.select(".info span[itemprop='name']"):
        print(items.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}'
    links = [url.format(page) for page in range(1, 6)]
    for link in links:
        parse_content(link)
```

This actually makes sure that no proxy is reused for each site. The order in which the proxies are tried is different for each site. If you are not fine with trying the same proxies again for a new site, just call `get_random_proxies_iter` outside of `parse_content` and feed it all the way down to `get_proxy`.